# Setting a custom runtime parameter every time I get the db cursor in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I wish to set a custom runtime parameter in postgresql every time I get the cursor for a connection.

I added the variables in postgresql.conf like so:

```
currentuser.name = 'not set'
currentuser.reasonid = -1
```

Now, my solution so far was to create a custom cursor class and then pass it as argument to the `cursor()` function:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

class mycursor(psycopg2.extensions.cursor):

    def __init__(self, username, *args, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs['username']
        del kwargs['username']
        super(mycursor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.execute("select set_config('currentuser.name', %s, false)", [username])


connection = psycopg2.connect(database="my_database", 
                              user="my_user", 
                              password="my_password", 
                              host='127.0.0.1')

cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=mycursor, username='michael')

cursor.execute("select current_setting('currentuser.name')")
user = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
print user
cursor.close()
```

This produces the `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "customdb.py", line 22, in <module>
   cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=mycursor, username='michael')
TypeError: 'username' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature for `connection.cursor` does not allow any additional parameter. That explains your error.

It would be simpler to sub-class the connection itself, because that way you could easily override the method `cursor`. Here is my implementation, that delegates all processing to an embedded `connection` object, except for the cursor creation :

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

class myconnection(psycopg2.extensions.connection):
    def __init__(self, database, user, password, host = 'localhost',
                port=5432, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__['conn'] = psycopg2.connect(dsn = None, database = database, user=user,
                                password=password, host=host, port=port, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__['username'] = user

    def cursor(self, username=None, **kwargs):
        curs = self.conn.cursor(**kwargs)
        if username is None:
            username = self.username 
        curs.execute("select set_config('currentuser.name', %s, false)", [username])
        return curs

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.conn, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.conn, name, value)


connection = myconnection(database="my_database", 
                          user="my_user", 
                          password="my_password", 
                          host='127.0.0.1')


cursor = connection.cursor(username='michael')

cursor.execute("select current_setting('currentuser.name')")
user = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
print user
cursor.close()
```

It correctly prints `michael`